# {Swift} let pin link?

Tags: swift

I do not find how link my let = pin
Help me please

My first code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var Point1S: MKMapView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let location = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(43.429837, 5.434837)

   Point1S.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location, 500, 500), animated: true)

    let pin = here
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Second code:

```
import MapKit

class MKPinAnnotationView : NSObject , MKAnnotation {
    var title: String?
    var subtitle: String?
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D

    init(title : String , subtitle : String , coordinate : CLLocationCoordinate2D) {

        self.title = title
        self.subtitle = subtitle
        self.coordinate = coordinate
    }

}
```

I do not know how to put on my first code in the let pin = the second code

thanks

Comment: are you asking how to instantiate your `MKPinAnnotationView` class?

Answer (score 0):

```
let pin = MKPinAnnotationView(title: "title", subtitle: "subtitle", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(27.33, 85.03))
```